# iOS: UITableview cell creation on stack

Tags: ios

I create UITableview and cells programmatically. When i create cell objects, does it store in stack memory? Does it store in stack for each cell objects i create? I want to optimize the code, so wanted to know it technically whats happening behind when creating table view cells through program.

Please advise!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects in Objective-C are created in the heap.

Use the standard method of dequeuing reusable cells and the system will
efficiently reuse them instead of allocating new ones when cells go off
the screen and new cells enter.

Here is a link to Apple's documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I know if we create any new objects, will create new memory in heap. But, my question is, if we create any table view cell objects or controls like tableview, view controllers etc. will be stored in stack itself if i'm not wrong?

Comment: You might have a pointer to these objects on the stack, but the memory for the objects is allocated from the heap and reference counted.

Comment: ok fine. Stack or heap finally its a memory. My another question was, every cell objects i create in Table view, each time memory will be used for every cell object. Is this right or wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, so follow up if I don't answer your question.  Memory for the cells are allocated from the heap (each cell is allocated separately) until there are enough cells to display all of the cells that are on screen.  Then as cells scroll off the screen, they are not deallocated but are instead put on a queue to be reused as new cells appear on screen.